# what is the purpose of arguments in main method in C language

Tags: c, arguments

I am learning C and noticed that if for simple programs (like printing something or other simple stuff) even if I remove the arguments in the main program it still works, but the book I am following puts these arguments in every single program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
// even works if i do int main() 
{
/* write your code here */

return 0;
}
```

I wanted to understand the reason for these arguments, why we put them and what are they used for?. maybe point out an example of a program where the program will not work if we removed these arguments from main function and point to what their purpose is?

Comment: It's same as in Java. `argc` tells you how may arguments you have (you have always one or more arguments because `argv[0] == "./prog"`). `argv` store any other arguments, that was passed when you started your program. `char *argv[]` or `char **argv` this are two notations you'll see. `argv` is basically 2D array of characters. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signature of main is:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv);
```

Where `argc` is the number of command line arguments passed in, which includes the actual name of the program, as invoked by the user.

`argv` contains the actual arguments, starting with index 1, since index `0` is the program name.

So, if you run your program like this:

```
./program hello world
```

Then:

`argc` would be `3`.

`argv[0]` would be `./program`.

`argv[1]` would be `hello`.

`argv[2]` would be `world`.

I hope this is clear enough for you.

If you want to understand it more clearly, go to these: [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point), [Link](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html)

Answer (score 2):

The permitted definitions of `main` in C are:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

If you don't use `argc` or `argv` parameters in your program, you can just use the first definition. These parameters are used to retrieve the number of arguments (`argc`) and their content (`argv`) in case you call your program in command line with arguments.

For example:

```
./a.out argument1 argument2
```

the value of `argc` is `3` and `argv` object is as if defined like this:

```
char *argv[] = {"./a.out", "argument1", "argument2", NULL};
```

Answer (score 1):

The arguments passed to the main method in C come from the command line when you execute the program.

You add them when you use the command line arguments as the mechanism for passing input information from the user to the program.

The program could still work if you have no command line arguments and passed nothing.  In that case the code would have to get all input information from another source (e.g. read from a file).

Answer (score 1):

They are used when you execute the program from the command line. argc has the number of arguments while argv is the individual arguments in string form

Answer (score 1):

Arguments to the main function are what you would type on command line for your program to execute. Let's look at them one-by-one.

`int argc`: Short for arguments count, this is the number of C-strings in argv array which is the second argument.

`char *argv[]`: This is array of strings. The first string is name of the binary executable that is generated when you compile your program. Rest of the strings are arguments to that program.

So, time for an example. Following simple program (let's call it *add*) takes two integers as command line arguments, prints their sum and exits. To stay to the point, this program performs minimum error checking.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a, b, sum;

    if(argc != 3) // program name + the two arguments
    {
        return -1;
    }
    a = atoi(argv[1]);
    b = atoi(argv[2]);
    sum = a + b;

    printf("Sum is: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled this program may be executed with following command:

```
$ ./add 25 31
```

where: `argv[0]` is *add*
       `argv[1]` is *25*
       `argv[2]` is *31*
and `argc` is 3

**How a main method without arguments works?**

The command line arguments `argc` and `argv` aren't required. So you could perfectly have a program like this:

```
int main()
{
    // other code here...
    return 0;
}
```

All that is required is that exactly one method in your program be named `main` (with one of the two recognised signatures: `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`). The operating system running the program will find that method and start executing your program from there (although actual starting point of programs is a different system defined routine).

Answer (score 1):

Like any function arguments, the purpose is not to make calling code work, but to provide data that the called function needs in order to operate correctly.

In the case of a `main` function, this is how the calling environment tells your program what options were given on the command line. Specifically, the first argument (traditionally named `argc` for "argument count") is how many "words" the command contained, and the second (`argv`, for "argument vector"), is an array (vector) of that length, containing the words themselves as standard null-terminated strings.

Thus when you type "rm -rf /", the `rm` program receives an `argc` of 3, and an `argv` containing "rm", "-rf", and "/". It can then interpret those arguments to know that you want to delete everything on the entire system.

Passing in the name of the command itself may seem odd, but is actually rather useful. For instance, the `true` command's job is to "do nothing, successfully" (exit immediately with a status of 0), while `false` should "do nothing, unsuccessfully" (exit with a status other than 0). These can both be pointed to the same program, using symlinks, and that program can decide whether to succeed or not based on the value of `argv[0]`.

A more elaborate example is the editor `vim`, which can be started with a variety of default options by invoking it with names like `view` (read only), `vimdiff` (compare two files side by side), `rvim` (restricted mode), `ex` (emulating a much simpler predecessor), and so on. These options and many more can also be specified as extra arguments, so there is presumably lots of code just "reading" `argv`.

Since you don't always care what arguments were used, it is permitted to define `main` with no parameters. The arguments on the command line will then be ignored, and your command will just run.

Answer (score 0):

So you can just pass parameters when you invoke the program from command line. Just imagine any command line tool that receives parameters, for example rm for remove files, normally you do like that:

$ rm file1

So, if the binary would be "rm", "file1" would be the first parameter. So argc value it is increased by one (it is the way to know how many arguments were passed to the binary), and argv[1] contains the string "file1".

You can imagine any other binary that receives any argument when you invoke.

Comment: Actually argv[0] would be "rm", allowing a program to change behaviour based on what name it was invoked under. I'm amused that we both chose that example though!